# How to decide which operation removes redundacies?

Tags: combinatorics

Please don't answer  by working backwards from the answer, or by appealing to arithmetic. Act as if you're learning this for the first time.

1. How can I deduce which operation ought fill in the red blank beneath?
2. Why can't it be subtraction?

#### [I shortened the original explanation](https://betterexplained.com/articles/easy-permutations-and-combinations/):

> **Quandary:** How many ways can I give $3$ gifts to $8$ people, if nobody receives $>1$ gift?
>
> **Explanation:** For combinations, order doesn’t matter. This raises an interesting detail of redundancies.
>
> For a moment, let's figure out how many ways we can rearrange 3 people. We've 3 choices for the first person, 2 for the second, and only 1 for the last. So we have $3 · 2 · 1$ ways to re-arrange 3 people. But this is a permutation! If you want to know the number of arrangements  for $N$ people, it’s just $N!$.
>
> So, for giving 3 gifts, there are $3! \; (= 6)$ variations for every choice we pick. To calculate how many combinations, just create all the permutations and $\color{red}{\text{_____ by all the redundancies}}$.  [...]

Comment: Sorry, what's the question?

Comment: Until I followed the link, it was not clear that you wish to give $3$ identical gifts to $8$ people in such a way that *no person receives more than one gift*.  Without that information, your question does not make sense.

Comment: It would be better to say if no person receives more than one gift since only three of the eight people will receive a gift.

Comment: Yes, it is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question "why can't you subtract":

How many ways can you give one gift to one person?

Comment: The answer is 1, but I'm not sure how this answers my confusion? There are no redundancies because everything is 1.

Comment: @Canada-Area51Proposal Okay, how many ways are there to give two gifts to one person?

Comment: 2 ways: Gift 1, 2. Or G2, 1. But how does this help? I'm missing the nub?